# Trying to locate the wear stub source for Android Deskclock

Tags: android, wear-os

I have found the source for Android Deskclock at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock but I cannot find the wear stub. I want to use it as an example for making the oscillating alert that shows and an alarm triggers on the wear device.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Android Wear nor its apps are open source, I'm afraid. You can decompile the clock APK from a watch or emulator, but that's probably as good as it's going to get.